# jQuery div expand height not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

Got a little problem with my jQuery.  I want it to expand the height of a div element, but can't seem to lick it. I'm using the following script:

```
<script>
$('.button').click(function(){
$('#footer_container').animate({height:'150px'}, 500);
});
</script>
```

where ".button" is the class of the hyperlink that triggers the animation:

"#footer_container" is the div that should expand to 150px from 75px.

I'm using

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

in the head of my doc.  Is it the wrong attachment (I'm using it for several other scripts I'm running on the page)?  Something I'm missing?
[I've posted the prototype on my test website](http://www.adamwebtest.com/).  It's the rectangular button at the bottom blue bar, that reads: Click to see our memberships. It should expand the div to reveal extra content, but does nothing :-(

Anyone have any ideas?  Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your culprit is that you are registering the handler before your element appears in DOM. SO eventually your `.button` doesn't get the click handler attached to it, since the element doesn't exist yet at the time of the script execution.

```
<div id="memberships">
<script>
$('.button').click(function(){
    $('#footer_container').animate({height:'150px'}, 500);
});
</script>
<a href="#" class="button">Click to see our memberships.</a>
</div>
```

Its always a safe bet is to attach it in Document ready handler. i.e `$(function(){...});` and place it anywhere on your page or in an external js file. Because it will be loaded only when the document where it is present is ready and elements are available.

So you would do :

```
$(function(){
     $('.button').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); //just prevent the default behavior of the hyperlink
        $('#footer_container').animate({height:'150px'}, 500);
    });

});
```

Also it is generally a bad practice to mix up html with the scripts. It is difficult to maintain and can display unpredictable behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The code should be in dom ready handler because when your script is executed the element `.button` is not yet added to the dom, so the selector will not return any result as a result the event handler will not get attached to the `.button` element

```
jQuery(function(){
    $('.button').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#footer_container').animate({height:'150px'}, 500);
    });
})
```